# PostgreSQL RubyMine Connection Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-connection, rubymine

I am having difficulty connecting to my PostgreSQL DB on Digital Ocean from within RubyMine.  Here are my settings for connecting to the DB within RubyMine:

Host:  http

Database: /ip_address/:80/my_site_name

user: my_user_name

password: hidden (but correct)

URL: jdbc:postgresql://http://ip_address/:80/my_site_name

ip_address is actually the ip address of the site and the same that I SSH into.  The error message I am getting is saying: "Incorrect driver and/or connection setting specified.  When I go the PostgreSQL driver section the Class says: org.postgresql.Driver, and the Dialect selected is PostgreSQL.  Use provided driver is checked with PostgreSQL ver. 42.1.1 showing.

Is there something I am missing in order to be able to connect to the DB from within RubyMine?  I was thinking a Port number might be incorrect but any and all help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: never mind.... not that this seems to be a pressing issue for others to interject help with but I was able to figure it out by ssh-ing into postgresql folder on Ubuntu server and editing a couple of files from there, then restarting my postgresql instance and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind.... not that this seems to be a pressing issue for others to interject help with but I was able to figure it out by ssh-ing into postgresql folder on Ubuntu server and editing a couple of files from there, then restarting my postgresql instance and it worked.